# Dagger2 - Injection of replacement modules without duplicating code

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have this setup of component plus module, say `FooComponent` and FooModule, which provides a simple singleton, which needs to be replaced in one of the test variants. Therefore, in the variant I have instead `FooTestComponent`, which inherits `FooComponent`, but its `@Modules` annotation points to another module instead, `FooTestModule`. So far `FooModule` provides only one dependency, so no problem with that.

However, as dependencies that need not to be replaced in tests are added to `FooModule`, I see myself forced to replicate all of the methods to provide them in `FooTestModule` too since they can't be extracted to a parent abstract module that both `FooModule` and `FooTestModule` inherit from. What is the way to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dagger 2 User's Guide Testing Section](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html) contains advice for this very scenario.

To summarize the advice there:

1. Subclassing modules in order to swap in test doubles leads to the situation where you have to resolve *all* of the dependencies even if they are unused. Don't do this!
2. Instead of the approach in point 1, use different component configurations to achieve this: you can have a TestComponent that extends ProductionComponent and uses different modules that include bindings for test doubles
3. To achieve point 2, organize your modules for testability. This means considering modules as a collection of published and internal bindings and making sure you have a separate module for each published binding that has a 'reasonable alternative' i.e., an alternative you might like to replace with a test double that is not a mere internal dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Alright well, so this is how it goes apparently: I'm really unsure this is the standard way of doing it, but deleting `FooTestComponent` and removing the annotations from `FooTestModule` allows `FooTestModule` to inherit from `FooModule`, and then you can instantiate `FooTestModule` where you override (but do not annotate) only the `@Provides` methods you need to mock.

Comment: If this is an Android project I would recommend having separate components with some code duplication for more flexibility.